# Solidity Contract not returning array

Tags: solidity, web3js, meteor

I am creating a contract of storing all the names and address of the users.

Then I returning the array of the names and address.

```
contract demo{

    address public user;
    uint  public  i=0;

    function demo(){
        user=msg.sender;
    }

    address[10] users;
    bytes32[10] name;

    function add(bytes32 _name){

        users[i]=user;
        name[i]=_name;
        i++;

    }

    function get_names() returns(bytes32[10]){
        return name;
    }

    function get_address() returns(address[10]){
        return users;
    }
  }
```

when I call the get_names function using web3, it did not returning the names of all the added users.

please help me what to do...

here is the code of web3

```
mycontract=web3.eth.contract(ABIArray).at(contract_Address);

    console.log(mycontract);
    var defaultAccount = web3.eth.defaultAccount;

    mycontract.get_names(function(err,res){

      console.log("get_names "+res);
      TemplateVar.set(template, "counter", res);

    })

     mycontract.get_address(function(err,res){



      console.log("get_address "+res);
      TemplateVar.set(template, "counter1", res);

    })


      mycontract.i(function(err,res){
        console.log("i "+res);
      TemplateVar.set(template, "counter2", res);

    })
```

And the returned value is not an array of names or address.

[image: the returned value is printed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing you are missing is the keyword **constant** for the functions returning the data. Here's your modified contract code that should work:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract Demo {
    address public user;
    uint public i = 0;

    function Demo() {
        user=msg.sender;
    }

    address[10] users;
    bytes32[10] name;

    function add(bytes32 _name) {
        users[i] = user;
        name[i] = _name;
        i++;
    }

    function get_names() constant returns(bytes32[10]) {
        return name;
    }

    function get_address() constant returns(address[10]) {
        return users;
    }
}
```

Comment: But when i call get_names using web3 , it gives "0x3035f432129b794ba9907232ccadbc138280a6355d3a573f4255407bf9255fe7" as a result. It is giving TxHash of the transaction. How do I get the value of the array name.